# Replace time in datetime column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How do I replace specific times in pandas column that is datetime format? I need to replace all times of `23:52:00` with `23:59:59` in `df.end`

```
data = [['site a',  '2021-03-05 23:52:00'], 
        ['site a', '2021-03-06 12:00:00'], 
        ['site b', '2021-04-08 23:00:00'],
        ['site c', '2021-04-09 23:52:00']] 
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'end'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Using this where statement, none of the times change. this due to this statement: `df['end'].dt.time == '23:52:00'`

```
np.where(df['end'].dt.time == '23:52:00', (df['end'].dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('23:59:59')), df['end'])

Out[74]: array(['2021-03-05T23:52:00.000000000', '2021-03-06T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2021-04-08T23:00:00.000000000', '2021-04-09T23:52:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer to compare using `datetime` objects, you can do (no need to use `np.where`):

```py
mask = df['end'].dt.time == pd.to_datetime('23:52:00').time()
df.loc[mask, 'end'] = df['end'].dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('23:59:59')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing wrong types, convert the time to sting:

```
mask = df['end'].dt.time.astype(str) == '23:52:00'
```

To replace the values found:

```
import datetime

df.loc[mask, 'end'] = df[mask]['end'] + datetime.timedelta(minutes=7)
```

replace "minutes=7" with the difference you want.

Answer (score -2):

you have to use date time not string. pandas.to_datetime('23:52:00')